# Modifying database value before passing it to the view

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

This is my current function to get all users:

```
function get_all() {
    return $this->db->get($this->tableName)->result();
}
```

Now I have a function that changes the mysql DATETIME to 'time ago'

```
timespan(human_to_unix($datetime),time());
```

How can I change all the mysql datetimes in the array that get_all produces before passing it to the controller and the view?

Secondly,
Is it correct to do this in the Model or should this be done in the Controller?

Comment: @safarov I wasn't sure if looping trough that array was permitted in a Model class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the model is fine for doing this.

You have a number of options simply iterate over the array
e.g.

```
$results = $this->db->get($this->tableName)->result();
foreach($results as $key=>$value)
{
  if($key=="<name of date time field>")
   {
     $results[$key]=timespan(human_to_unix($value),time());
   }
}
```

return $results;

if 5.3 php
Use something like array_walk with anonymous function

```
$results = $this->db->get($this->tableName)->result();

    array_walk($results, function (&$v, $k) { if($k=="<name of date time field>"){$v=timespan(human_to_unix($v),time()} });
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose somethin like:

```
function get_all() {
    $arr = $this->db->get($this->tableName)->result();
    foreach(array_keys($arr) as $h)
        $arr[$h]->datetime = timespan(human_to_unix($arr[$h]->datetime),time());

    return $arr;
}
```

I can't tell what the functions `timespan` and `human_to_unix` does exactly.